# Working with model forms and choose multiple items from many to many fields

Tags: django

I'm trying to using model forms and when creating a new mngreq,and i want to choose items from a manytomany django model fields that is who_user fields
when i use admin site everything is ok but when i test it from my own html code it shows up but didnt save to database

here is my code

```
    # models.py



class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/users', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()


    class ManagementReq(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        who_user = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
        content = models.TextField()
        creation_time = models.TimeField()
        attach = models.FileField(upload_to='media/manreqapp/files/%Y-%m-%d', null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('mngreq-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

```
# views.py
@login_required
def MngReqCreate(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            mngreqform = MngReqForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES)
            if mngreqform.is_valid():
                mngreq = mngreqform.save(commit=False)
                mngreq.author = request.user
                mngreq.creation_time = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
                mngreq.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manreqapp:mngreq-list'))
        else:
            mngreqform = MngReqForm()
        context = {
            'form': mngreqform,
        }
        return render(request, 'manreqapp/managementreq_create.html', context)
```

```
{% extends "manreqapp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block extra_css %}
<style>
    .vertical-center { display: flex; justify-content: center; }
</style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="vapid-key" content="{{ vapid_key }}">
    {% if user.id %}
        <meta name="user_id" content="{{ user.id }}">
    {% endif %}

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock extra_css %}

{% block content %}
<legend style="color:#f68e20">درخواست های مدیریت</legend>
<div class="content-section" style="background-color:white">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fieldWrapper" style="background-color:#a7a9ac">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.type.errors }}
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.type.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           {% render_field form.type class="form-control" style="background-color:#a7a9ac" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper" style="background-color:#f68e20">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.title.errors }}
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.title.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           {% render_field form.title class="form-control" style="background-color:#f68e20" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper" style="background-color:#a7a9ac">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.who_group.errors }}
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.who_group.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           {% render_field form.who_group class="form-control" style="background-color:#a7a9ac" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper mb-5" style="background-color:#f68e20">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.who_user.errors }}
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.who_user.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           {% render_field form.who_user class="form-control" style="background-color:#f68e20" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper" style="background-color:#a7a9ac">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.content.errors }}
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.content.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           {% render_field form.content class="form-control" style="background-color:#a7a9ac" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper" style="background-color:#f68e20">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.attach.errors }}
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form.attach.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           {% render_field form.attach class="form-control" style="background-color:#f68e20" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="btn-success: ">ثبت</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content%}
```

please help me
thanks to all

Comment: Hi Amir, do you get any errors? What db are you trying to save this to?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt get any errors. And im using sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

After you’ve manually(`commit=false`) saved the instance produced by the form, you need to invoke `save_m2m()` to save the many-to-many form data. m2m required the object saved first, [read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)